# How to update multiple rows using a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I am executing the sub query everything is fine as expected and Now I am using the same query to update a column based on the sub query results but it says sub query returned more than 1 row which make sense..How should I solve this ..

```
begin transaction
update trn_RatingAuto                                                        
set Rate  = 0 
where rate = (
SELECT ar.Rate
FROM trn_account ta
INNER JOIN trn_risk tr  ON ta.AccountId=tr.AccountId
inner join trn_option ot on tr.riskid = ot.riskid
INNER JOIN trn_Rating ra ON ot.RatingId = ra.RatingId
INNER JOIN trn_RatingAuto ar on ra.RatingId = ar.RatingId
where  ar.Rate is null 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IN` instead of `=`.

```
update trn_RatingAuto
set Rate  = 0 
where rate IN (
  SELECT ar.Rate
  FROM trn_account ta
  INNER JOIN trn_risk tr  ON ta.AccountId=tr.AccountId
  inner join trn_option ot on tr.riskid = ot.riskid
  INNER JOIN trn_Rating ra ON ot.RatingId = ra.RatingId
  INNER JOIN trn_RatingAuto ar on ra.RatingId = ar.RatingId
  where  ar.Rate is null 
)
```

EDIT:

You can also do an update this way:

```
update ar
set Rate  = 0 
FROM trn_account ta
INNER JOIN trn_risk tr  ON ta.AccountId=tr.AccountId
inner join trn_option ot on tr.riskid = ot.riskid
INNER JOIN trn_Rating ra ON ot.RatingId = ra.RatingId
INNER JOIN trn_RatingAuto ar on ra.RatingId = ar.RatingId
where  ar.Rate is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your where from `=` to `in`?

```
begin transaction
update trn_RatingAuto                                                        
set Rate  = 0 
where rate in (
SELECT ar.Rate
FROM trn_account ta
INNER JOIN trn_risk tr  ON ta.AccountId=tr.AccountId
inner join trn_option ot on tr.riskid = ot.riskid
INNER JOIN trn_Rating ra ON ot.RatingId = ra.RatingId
INNER JOIN trn_RatingAuto ar on ra.RatingId = ar.RatingId
where  ar.Rate is null 
)
```

Comment: The query was returning 0 row(s) which I tried earlier and Failed..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update multiple rows, you need to change your query to be an "update from" query...

[sql server 2005 'update from' query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029854/sql-server-2005-update-from-query)

like:

```
 update trn_RatingAuto
   set Rate  = 0  
 from trn_RatingAuto
 join (...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script on SQLServer2008R2, maybe it will help you

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Rate  = 0 
FROM (
      SELECT ar.Rate
      FROM trn_account ta INNER JOIN trn_risk tr  ON ta.AccountId=tr.AccountId
                          INNER JOIN trn_option ot ON tr.riskid = ot.riskid
                          INNER JOIN trn_Rating ra ON ot.RatingId = ra.RatingId
                          INNER JOIN trn_RatingAuto ar ON ra.RatingId = ar.RatingId
      WHERE  ar.Rate is null
      ) x
```